# Datatable funcionalidad

Tags: javascript, datatables

Buen dia quisiera saber que datatble o funcionalidad debo de descargar/usar/implemnetar para tener el efecto de la imagen me refiero que cuando le das click en la boton verde te desplega la informacion abajo (salary en este caso) gracias
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La funcionalidad  se llama
https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

Comment: https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

Answer (score 0):

Debes incluir estos scripts en la Cabecera del documento entre  y

este se encarga de la parte visual

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></script>
```

este se encarga de las funcionalidades

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

este se encarga de crearla

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready( function () {
      //pilas con el id, en este caso es 'myTable' depende del tuyo
      $('#myTable').DataTable();
  } );
</script>
```

espero te sirva

Answer (score 0):

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo.
CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/t/bs-3.3.6/dt-1.10.11,r-2.0.2/datatables.min.css" />
```

JS:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="application/javascript" language="JavaScript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/t/bs-3.3.6/dt-1.10.11,r-2.0.2/datatables.min.js" type="application/javascript" language="JavaScript"></script>
```

Datatables:

```
<div class="container">


<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#example2-tab1" aria-controls="example2-tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#example2-tab2" aria-controls="example2-tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="example2-tab1">
        <table id="example2-tab1-dt" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Start date</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <th>Extension</th>
                    <th>Department</th>
                    <th>Supervisor</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                    <td>System Architect</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>2011/04/25</td>
                    <td>$320,800</td>
                    <td>123-456-7890</td>
                    <td>1230</td>
                    <td>IT</td>
                    <td>Dai Rios</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                    <td>Accountant</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>63</td>
                    <td>2011/07/25</td>
                    <td>$170,750</td>
                    <td>123-456-7890</td>
                    <td>1231</td>
                    <td>Accounting</td>
                    <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                    <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>66</td>
                    <td>2009/01/12</td>
                    <td>$86,000</td>
                    <td>123-456-7890</td>
                    <td>1232</td>
                    <td>Marketing</td>
                    <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="example2-tab2">
        <table id="example2-tab2-dt" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Start date</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <th>Extension</th>
                    <th>Department</th>
                    <th>Supervisor</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                    <td>System Architect</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>2011/04/25</td>
                    <td>$320,800</td>
                    <td>123-456-7890</td>
                    <td>1230</td>
                    <td>IT</td>
                    <td>Dai Rios</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                    <td>Accountant</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>63</td>
                    <td>2011/07/25</td>
                    <td>$170,750</td>
                    <td>123-456-7890</td>
                    <td>1231</td>
                    <td>Accounting</td>
                    <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                    <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>66</td>
                    <td>2009/01/12</td>
                    <td>$86,000</td>
                    <td>123-456-7890</td>
                    <td>1232</td>
                    <td>Marketing</td>
                    <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#example2-tab1-dt').DataTable({
      responsive: true
   });

$('#example2-tab2-dt').DataTable({
      responsive: true
   });

$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e){
      $($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable()
         .columns.adjust()
         .responsive.recalc();
   });

});
`

Espero que se entienda.

Suerte.